Nuxt 2 - how read dynamic images added in project
I made a nuxt 2 app that allows user to upload images from a page. I've installed   "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1", in my project and everything works fine locally.
Instead on my VPS, after deployment, if I try to read the image, I have an error (not found). I've checked if the image exists in folder, and the image was there. But if I try to type the path of the image on the browser, I will see an error not found. Locally it works.
This is my images.js file where I upload the images from Express and multer
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const imageController = require('../controllers/image');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

let pathUpload = 'assets/img/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, pathUpload);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let fullpath = Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname;
    cb(null, fullpath);
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), imageController.uploadImage);
router.get('/:id', imageController.getImage);
router.get('/', imageController.getAllImage);

module.exports = router;

This is the page where i need to show all images :
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="img-list"
        v-for="(image,i) in this.images_list"
        :key="i + image"
      >
      <!-- Result of require is `~/assets/img/image_1.png` -->
        <img :src="require(`~/assets/img/${image.path}`)" />
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
     selectedFile: null,        
  }),
  async fetch({store, params}) {
    // get images 
    await store.dispatch('fetchAllImages')
  },
  computed: {
    images_list() {
        return this.$store.state.images
    },
  },      
}
</script>

If I type the path like the below, it works, otherwise dynamic code does not work.
<img :src="require('~/assets/img/image_1.png')" />

Is there a way to read dynamic images from assets or static folder?
In my VPS the images were in the correct path, like locally, but if I type the path on the URL, I can't reach the images.
Ex.

www.websiteurl.com/_nuxt/assets/img/images_1.png
www.websiteurl.com/.nuxt/assets/img/images_1.png
www.websiteurl.com/assets/img/images_1.png


It works fine locally because you have a node server to run and serve the images. Not sure where you host and how you render you app but I assume your host is static. So the only viable and easy way to access images is through the static directory. Have you tried that?

I use a VPS server with node 18 and mongodb. It worked on production, and the images were saved correctly. But i can't display because path is wrong. I tried also the static assets, but same thing.
The only way i found is to save the images in dist folder, but on build command the dist folder will be remade, so i will lost the images saved.

Hm I am not sure if you can reference something from the outside, should be. Just make a backup on your backend of the hosted URLs of your images and generate them back there while generating the app.
